# System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: true, Actual: false when there's no statement to return true or false

Tags: apex, unit-test

The previous dev person left without leaving any documentation on the Apex Trigger, and this trigger is blocking us from implementing the new process. I check off Activate in the sandbox and am deploying the change set. While doing so I encounter the error:

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: true, Actual: false
> Stack Trace: Class.TaskHandlerTest.testCreateEmailTaskAndSetFollowUpToExistingDemoTasks: line 12, column 1

While, it doesn't appear to me (who don't handle Apex) there's a statement that may return True or False.

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, before insert, before update){
    TaskHandler handler = new TaskHandler(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.old, Trigger.new);
    if (Trigger.isBefore){
        handler.bulkBefore();
        if (Trigger.isDelete){
            for (SObject so : Trigger.old){

            }
        } else if (Trigger.isInsert){
            for (SObject so : Trigger.new){
                handler.beforeInsert(so);
            }
        } else if (Trigger.isUpdate){
            for (SObject so : Trigger.old){
                handler.beforeUpdate(so, Trigger.newMap.get(so.Id));
            }
        }
    } else {
        handler.bulkAfter();
        if (Trigger.isDelete){
            for (SObject so : Trigger.old){
                handler.afterDelete(so);
            }
        } else if (Trigger.isInsert){
            for (SObject so : Trigger.new){
                handler.afterInsert(so);
            }
        } else if (Trigger.isUpdate){
            for (SObject so : Trigger.old){
                handler.afterUpdate(so, Trigger.newMap.get(so.Id));
            }
        }
        handler.postProcessing();
    }
}
```

Comment: The immediate error isn't coming from this trigger, but rather the unit test class for `TaskHandler` (named `TaskHandlerTest`). There's a method call to `System.assert()` somewhere in there that  is returning `false` and causing that test to fail. We'll need to see the code for both `TaskHandler` and `TaskHandlerTest` to be able to provide any insight, but if you're deactivating the trigger that'll cause some issues with any test class that depends on that trigger being active. You can [edit] your question to add more information/code.

Comment: You may need to simply remove or comment out the entire body of the test class if you are deactivating its corresponding trigger. While you can try this yourself depending on your risk appetite, the best course is to work with a developer to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error is in fact from other Apex class. I first tried again by commenting out the trigger, and still the production did not take it. Now I commented out both the trigger and the apex class (TaskHandlerTest), and now the error is about code coverage (39%). I just need to deactivate this trigger; why is this so difficult...